# GotError [RequestError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443

Tags: javascript, sql, asynchronous, fetch, passport.js

HELP!
trying to serialize/deserialize in my first oauth app and if i try to use fetch to make an api call it is not recognized, when i use 'got' i get GotError [RequestError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443

i was able to save google users into my own psql database using the google+ api, but wasnt using asynchronous functions. now im trying to get the cookie by serializing but i get the error whenever i try.

my app.js route is app.post('/users', db.createUser)

```
const passport = require('passport');
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20');
const db = require('../queries')
const keys = require('./keys');
const got = require('got');

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    console.log(user);
    done(null, user.id);
})

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    console.log(id);
    db.getById(id).then(done(null, user));
})

passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy({
        //options for the google strategy
        callbackURL: '/auth/google/redirect',
        clientID: keys.google.clientID,
        clientSecret: keys.google.clientSecret
    }, (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
      
            let user = {
                username: profile.displayName,
                googleid: profile.id
            }

            const postUser = async(user) => {
                let url = '/users';
                console.log('jajajajajajjajajajajjjajajajajjaj');
                try {
                    const response = await got(url, {
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                        },
                        mode: 'cors',
                        body: JSON.stringify(user)
                    })
                    if (response.ok) {
                        let jsonResponse = await response.json();
                        return jsonResponse;
                    }
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log(error)
                }
            }

            postUser(user).then((user) => {
                done(null, user)
            });
        }
    )
)
```